# UITableViewCell initWithCoder never called - Using Storyboards

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I'm working with Storyboards again and I'm not the best with them.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"browse_cell";
    VJBrowseLargeTableViewCell *cell = (VJBrowseLargeTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.artistLabel.text = currentVideo.artist;

}
```

In my .h for the cell I have:

```
@interface VJBrowseLargeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *backgroundImageView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *artistLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *songTitleLabel;

@end
```

.m for the cell:

```
 @implementation VJBrowseLargeTableViewCell

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self initialize];
}

- (void)initialize {

    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    self.artistLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.artistLabel.font = [UIFont vojiBoldFontWithSize:20];
    self.artistLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    self.artistLabel.numberOfLines = 1;


    self.songTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.songTitleLabel.font = [UIFont vojiRegularFontWithSize:16];
    self.songTitleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    self.songTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
}
```

For my tableView, I've registered the cell:

```
 [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"browse_cell"];
```

---

None of the methods in my custom cell are being called, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is crashing at `cell.artistLabel.text = currentVideo.artist;`. It seems my cell code isn't hooked up to the Storyboard cell properly.

However, in Storyboard, I do have the `class` set correctly, and I have the `identifier` set correctly.

Comment: Also, if I break in `cellForRow` after the cell is dequeued, it prints out as a `UITableViewCell` and not my custom class

Comment: OK, I found one bug. I wasn't registering the right class. Now it's - `    [self.tableView registerClass:[VJBrowseLargeTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"browse_cell"];
`... so it's returning the correct cell now.

Comment: However, neither `initWithCoder` nor `awakeFromNib` are getting called in the cell, although `layoutSubviews` is...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to register the class in this case, but since you are, you are registering `[UITableViewCell class]` rather than `[VJBrowseLargeTableViewCell class]` for the reuse identifier.

Comment: Yeah - I caught that and fixed it. But neither `initWithCoder` nor `awakeFromNib` are getting called in the cell class.

Comment: Oh for that... I think you need to override `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"browse_cell"];
```

You should register correct class name:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[VJBrowseLargeTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"browse_cell"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The designated initializer for UITableViewCells is actually `initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`, rather than `initWithCoder: (NSCoder*)aDecoder` (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:)). Try overriding that initializer instead.